# Failed to create view from XIB UI using Xamarin and MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm have a Xamarin.iOS app. It was written some time ago and used XIB to define user interface. I want to add new view (and controller for it) but every time I'm adding new page and launching the app I get the following error:

```
Failed to marshal the Objective-C object 0x17a37a70 (type: LoginView). Could not find an existing managed instance for this object, nor was it possible to create a new managed instance (because the type 'Touch.LoginView' does not have a constructor that takes one IntPtr argument).
Additional information:
    Selector: viewDidLoad
    Method: Touch.LoginView:ViewDidLoad ()
```

What is more interesting if I'm creating new view by copying existing one and renaming it - everything works fine. I tried to figure out what is the difference but the only thing I found is the following:
[image] 
[image]

If you noticed the extra level of hierarchy was added.
What it is the level and why my app continue to fail with newly created view (i have to copy existing one if I want new view).

Comment: I think you need to get rid of that top layer, it's the view controller.  Then associate the View with the File's owner and set the class for the View.

Comment: but that hierarchy created by default. Do you think I have something in app trying to load this "default" view inproperly?

Comment: I could be wrong but it seems that started happening recently.  I had the same thing happen after recent updates.

Answer (score 6):

This kind of error message can be a real pain normally. In your case, you're pretty lucky as there is a very simple fix to this. When working with xib or storyboard files, you want to have the following in your controllers:

```
public Test1ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
}
```

A general explanation of the error message you are seeing:

> Such issues are, 99% of the time, related to a managed instance with no
>   reference. At some point the GC will collect it and it will crash whenever some native code tries to callback into the (now freed) managed instance.

Comment: You might find yourself here if you are doing MVVMCross with storyboards.

Comment: I have this in my code in each of my controllers, but still this crash is being reported for a very small amount of users. I'm using mvvm lite with storyboards, any advice?